# Where struct vnode is defined from OS X?

Tags: macos, header, filesystems

I'm looking for a header file that defines *struct vnode* from Mac OS X 10.10.
I googled a bit and could find the following link that states *bsd/sys/vnode_internal.h* contains the definition.

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.40.9/bsd/sys/vnode_internal.h

However I can't find the file from my OS X typically under */usr/include*. Can you help finding the definition?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this question. You can simply download xnu source base from 
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/ and you can also build it. You can find all of xnu kernel data structures from the source base.